# Get an Error when running .NET Core application with AWS Lambda Function (AWS Lambda Project with Test (.Net Framework))

Tags: .net, .net-core, coreclr

The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
The program '[10348] dotnet-lambda-test-tool-6.0.exe' has exited with code 2147516570 (0x8000809a).

Get an Error when running .NET Core application with AWS Lambda Function (AWS Lambda Project with Test (.Net Framework)). How to solve this issue?

I need a help to solve this issue.

Comment: Did not use AWS before, but the elephant in the room seems to be: ".NET Core" != ".NET Framework"